# Color Calibrate Dual Monitor XP SP2

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, color-profiles, display-settings

This topic has been touched on [before](https://superuser.com/questions/127533/colors-differ-in-the-dual-monitor) but not really answered.  I have a dual monitor system and the colors differ wildly.  I currently live Buenos Aires where color correction hardware costs premium prices.  I do some graphic design, but don't require a pro-level calibration.  That said, I'd like my monitors to be set as close to "true color" as possible.

I've located the useful and free [Monitor Calibration Wizard](http://www.hex2bit.com/products/product_mcw.asp), but it seems to adjust the entire system internally at startup.  I could use the [Microsoft Color Control Panel Applet](http://www.microsoft.com/prophoto/downloads/colorcontrol.aspx) to set a different ICC or ICM profile for each monitor, but the Monitor Calibration Wizard outputs its own format for profiles.

Comment: What's the problem with adjusting the entire system internally at startup?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend **Calibrize**

1. Download and install [Calibrize](http://www.calibrize.com/)
2. Adjust your monitor so you view it directly on adjust your lights to how they are when you are working.
3. Run calibrize and follow the tutorial it will generate a Windows compatible color profile in your Documents folder.
4. Rename the Profile to the name of your monitor.
5. Repeat 2 - 4 having moved Calibrize to your second monitor.
6. Load the profiles to the corresponding monitors in windows color management.

Comment: What made the old Monitor Calibration Wizard more powerful than other such tools was that it allowed a multi-level gamma calibration where you could calibrate several points along each channel's brightness curve. I've never found another tool that offers that :(