# Dual Monitor Color Issue

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, colors

My monitor is connected to my laptop via HDMI. The color on the monitor in dual screen is a bit weird. It's kinda yellowish. I tried changing the color on the monitor itself, doesn't help. When I went to calibrate color (windows 7), whenever I click sliders/buttons in that window, the screens colors shift to what they're supposed to be, but only so long the button/slider is held.

The issue isn't necessarily that the colors are off, the problem I have is that it CAN be right, it just only happens when I click certain things in the color calibration screen, and then immediately reverts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Colors differ in the dual monitor](http://superuser.com/questions/127533/colors-differ-in-the-dual-monitor)

Comment: It doesn't look like the duplicate addresses the issue here.  It appears that the issue raised is that adjustments aren't retained.

Answer (score 1):

I think that "calibrating color" in Windows 7 is a tool to create a color calibration .icc file that tells Windows how to render colors on a monitor. If they're the same monitor, try loading the same .icc calibration file (your computer comes with some basic ones, your monitor might come with some more accurate ones).

To look at those, right click on your desktop and go to Screen Resolution>Advanced Settings> Color Management>Color Management..., or run colorcpl.exe.

In devices, set the same color profile for each display, or if they're different monitors, try to find accurate or similar color profiles for both.

I don't know if this will work, it's just what I would try in the situation.

Answer (score 0):

If it's yellowish it means it's missing blue, the probable cause being the blue pin of the signal has an improper contact.
Check your wire connectivity.

Open paintbrush to see what colors are missing/not displayed.
You should see no blue in the color bar if what you described is correct.

Comment: Well, the problem isn't necessarily that the colors are off, but that they are correct when I click specific things in the color calibration window, and not otherwise.

Comment: One easy way to calibrate is to make sure white is white. That will mean RGB values are even. If you cannot obtain pure white no matter what you do then certainly one of the RGB channels is not good.When calibrating, if you see yellowish, increase blue level, if you see purple/pink increase green level and if you see blueish-cyan increase red level.