# Issues with images/video that look orange and tanned

Tags: colors, dell-inspiron, high-definition, contrast

so I bought a new Dell laptop yesterday and when I transferred my images over, everyone looks tanned/orange. This applies to images on the internet and video too, such as YouTube.

Is this the after effects of a Full HD Screen? Because it doesn't look right to me, I have attached examples for side by side comparisons.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnq6T.jpg)
[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6evFh.jpg)

Comment: Different screens display colors differently. Nothing is wrong. If the colors on the new screen bother you, you can calibrate your display color in Windows (search for "Calibrate Display Color").

Comment: Hi, so it's normal for people to look orange?

Comment: @user1686 

Not sure this is the default setting. I was browsing and noticed images and video didn't look right. Like they are tanned/chiseled. I wouldn't know what RGB colours to set it to to make it look normal

Comment: What actually makes the one on the right even worse is that the one on the left is actually too **blue**. They're both wrong, just one is more wrong than the other. You need some sort of colour calibration system, either by eye or by colorimeter, see the proposed duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Colors differ in the dual monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/127533/colors-differ-in-the-dual-monitor)

Comment: No as I'm not using a dual monitor I just put the 2 laptops side by side for comparison. I just want to know how can I change the setting of the Dell Laptop to make it look normal?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you're using dual or single, it just happens that both of your examples are terribly calibrated, in unfortunately different directions which makes them both look even worse than they are. if you buy a colorimeter, then **both** really need doing.

Answer (score -1):

I think what your seeing is a "truer" version of the images, but since you're used to the lenovo screen (which looks slightly less vibrant, possibly from age, possibly from settings) it appears odd to you. IMO the dell looks proper, you could try turning down vibrance and/or saturation if you want to go back, but if it was me I'd let myself adjust to the new screen and the "shock" from the difference between the two screens will dissipate.

Comment: Yes because my family members all look orange and toned lol for example where there is supposed to be a white wall, it's not white, it's of a cream/beige colour so how can I make it somewhat compareable?

Comment: JJC - they're both wrong, in opposite directions, which makes the resulting difference look even worse. There's no way the right-most is "truer" is just wrong in a different way to the one on the left. Both are miles out.

Comment: @Tetsujin

What RGB settings do I need to do? I've never done this before

Comment: See the link in the duplicate question - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/computer-display-calibration-101.html for a beginner's guide.

Comment: The issue is how do I adjust something that I don't know what it's supposed to look like? As you said the Dell laptop is really wrong, but the left is a bit wrong

Comment: You adjust it by reading the link I keep providing for you & working from there.

Comment: If you cant adjust it because you "don't know what it's supposed to look like", how do you know the dell laptop is "really wrong"? Either you got a defective unit that is somehow more vibrant than all the others, or everyone else who buys a dell is ok with it, hence my theory that you might just be used to the pale/washed out image on the lenovo and it's a big difference for you

Comment: @JJC8008 - it's a fine theory… but it's working from a false premise. If you take either of those photos & adjust white balance to the presumably [though of course not guaranteed] white doors behind, then you will quite clearly see that **both** are badly wrong. If you didn't understand what I just said, then feel free to not postulate further.

Comment: Well neither of you provided me with an answer so I asked a different forum and they gave me a proper step by step answer, nothing to do with dual monitors and I didn't have to buy something for $150. The issue was the gamma setting when calibrating, the constrast was high hence the orange colour and the red and green needed to be lowered just a tad bit while the blue stayed the same regarding the RGB sliders. Better to close the topic now. Thanks

Comment: That's pretty much what I referred you to. You obviously didn't read it., or if you did, you didn't understand it. I already told you it was nothing to do with dual monitors, I also told you [via the duplicate question link, and again separately in this thread] that your best method was a hardware colorimeter, & secondary was to just play with the settings in accordance with the codinghorror rough guide.

Answer (score -1):

It's ok I figured it out! It was the gamma setting! I was messing around with it and saw huge changes!